# How to convert a datetime ('2019-06-05T10:37:29.353+0100') to UTC timestamp using Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I want to convert `datetime`, i.e. `2019-06-05T10:37:29.353+0100`, to UTC timestamp in Python3.

I understand that `+0100` represents the timezone. Why do `+0100`, `+0200`, and `+0300` all convert to the same timestamp?

How can I convert a `datetime` containing a timezone to a UTC timestamp?

```
>>> d=datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-06-05T10:37:29.353+0100', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
>>> unixtime = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
>>> unixtime
1559723849.0
>>> d=datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-06-05T10:37:29.353+0200', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
>>> unixtime = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
>>> unixtime
1559723849.0
>>> d=datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-06-05T10:37:29.353+0300', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
>>> unixtime = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
>>> unixtime
1559723849.0
```

Comment: you could use the `timestamp()` method of the datetime object straight away

Comment: btw. it's a shame that [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) can't parse this (although ISO 8601 compatible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's some more explanations (see comments) how to convert back and forth between timestamps as strings with UTC offset and POSIX timestamps.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

s = '2019-06-05T10:37:29.353+0100'
# to datetime object
dt = datetime.strptime('2019-06-05T10:37:29.353+0100', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
# note that the object has tzinfo set to a specific timedelta:
print(repr(dt))
>>> datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 5, 10, 37, 29, 353000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)))

# you could store this info
dt_UTCoffset = dt.utcoffset() # datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)

# to get POSIX seconds since the epoch:
ts = dt.timestamp()

# and back to datetime:
dt_from_ts = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=timezone.utc)
# note that this is a UTC timestamp; the UTC offset is zero:
print(dt_from_ts.isoformat())
>>> 2019-06-05T09:37:29.353000+00:00

# instead of UTC, you could also set a UTC offset:
dt_from_ts = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=timezone(dt_UTCoffset))
print(dt_from_ts.isoformat())
>>> 2019-06-05T10:37:29.353000+01:00
```

...And a note on a pitfall when working with datetime in Python: if you convert from timestamp to datetime and *don't set the tz property*, local time is returned (same applies the other way 'round!):

```
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)) # I'm on CEST at the moment, so UTC+2
>>> 2019-06-05 11:37:29.353000
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm also on UTC+2 (Denmark). Shouldn't your example time (local time) be ~9.30 then? Furthermore, given a UTC time (UTC offset is 0), the local time at that point can always be derived right? I don't need to store your `dt_UTCoffset` in the database?

Comment: @Shuzheng: the input in my example is ~9:37h UTC, so 11:37 UTC+2. Python can determine local time based on the OS settings. If you need to determine the *specific time zone*, you'll need 3rd party libraries like [tzlocal](https://pypi.org/project/tzlocal/).